# Euler's Theorem Limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Does anyone know why $$\lim_{n\to ∞}\left(1+\frac {i\pi} n\right)^n=-1$$?

From my own intuition, subbing in $n=∞$ means that the $\frac x n \to 0$ and therefore the limit will be 1 as opposed to -1. I'm stumped at this part. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$?

Comment: I recommend [this video](https://youtu.be/-dhHrg-KbJ0) from Mathologer

Comment: In particular, I think the visualization that begins about 13 minutes in seems like the kind of intuition that you're looking for.

Comment: Regarding your "intuitive" argument, note that $1^\infty$ is an "indeterminate form", which means that plugging in as you have will not produce a correct answer.

Comment: Ahh i see, how would I work out this limit then? Hypothetically, if a question in a test asked you to show why the limit = -1, how would I show it? I just quickly skimmed through the video, so I can't be sure if he covered this in it, but if he did, let me know and I'll watch through again!

Comment: That depends what class you're in.  However, in most contexts where you are using both limits and complex numbers, it should be fine to say that $e^{i \pi} = -1$ as a consequence of Euler's formula.  If you're going to go through the trouble of proving the limit for $e^{i\pi}$, it's usually convenient to prove the limit for $e^{ix}$ for arbitrary real numbers $x$ while you're in the process, and proving Euler's formula is rarely given as an exercise.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense. In saying this, I'm currently looking at question that requires you to use the limit to prove Euler's Identity. To give some context, the question's sort of based on logarithmic spirals and stacking similar right triangles.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, that was part of what I was trying to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, please tell me if there is any problems with it (just a technicality, I'm only doing it for rational $n$ as I think that the continuity of $(1+\frac {i\pi}n)^n$ implies the limit for any real $n$):

$$e^{i\pi}=\lim_{n \to ∞} \left (1+ \frac {i\pi} n \right) $$
Using rewriting $1+\frac {i\pi} n$ as:
$$\sqrt {1 + \frac {\pi^2} {n^2}}^n \left(\cos(\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) +i\sin(\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) \right)^n$$

Then using De Moivre's formula on this rewritten number (which can be proven by induction for integer $n$, and then for rational $n$, without Euler's formula),
$$\left(1+ \frac {i\pi} n\right)^n=\sqrt {1 + \frac {\pi^2} {n^2}}^n \left(\cos(\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) +i\sin(\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) \right)^n$$
$$=\sqrt {1 + \frac {\pi^2} {n^2}}^n \left(\cos(n\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) +i\sin(n\arctan(\frac {\pi} n) \right)$$

As $n \to ∞$, the moduli raised to the $n$-th power $\to 1$ and the limit for $n \arctan ({\pi} n)$ will turn into $\pi$.

Plug $\pi$ into the $\cos$ and $\sin$ will give the answer of $-1$.

$$\therefore e^{i\pi}= \lim_{n \to ∞} \left (1+\frac {i\pi} n \right) =-1$$

Reference:
[See Post #12](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/method-of-proving-eulers-formula.660252/)

Answer (score 0):

This is $e^{i\pi}$, which is, by Euler's formula, $-1$.

Comment: I was wondering why the limit becomes -1. I understand that it is Euler's identity, but I'm lost to why the limit turns into -1

Comment: @spuddy : $e^{i\pi} = \cos\pi +i\sin\pi = -1 + i\cdot 0 = -1~;~~~ e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x~~~$

Answer (score 0):

To prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x$, use $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} \frac{x^k}{n^k}$.
For each $k$, $\binom{n}{k} \frac{x^k}{n^k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{n^k} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

$\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{n^k}$ is increasing with $n$ and $\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$
This leads to the series for $e^x$ which is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 0):

One can prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n=\cos x +i\sin x$$ for all $x\in \mathbb {R} $. Your desired result then follows by putting $x=\pi$.

Easiest route to this formula is the following lemma of MSE user Thomas Andrews:

> **Lemma**: If $\{a_n\} $ is a sequence of complex numbers such that $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ then $a_n^n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty $.

For the current problem use $$a_n=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{ix}{n}}{\cos\dfrac{x}{n}+i\sin\dfrac {x} {n}} $$ and show that $n(a_n-1)\to 0$. Then $a_n^n\to 1$ and our job is done.